# Combining Angular controllers

Tags: angularjs

I have an existing angular project that has something really weird with the controller. It looks like the following.

```
app.controller('AppController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
var app = app_application;
angular.extend($scope, app);
$scope.itTransports = app.state.itTransports;
}]);
```

I have a proof of concept for something I am trying to do on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AESW4/) and an attempt to mix the above controller and my concept [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a8kN7/) but I cant seem to get it to work. I think it is something to do with the weird way the above controller works but I cant break it too badly and cant talk to the previous developer. I would think that if a combination cant be done then I would need some way for one controller to call another one but I want to make sure before I go down that path.

Edit: My main goal is to add functionality to check if the cookie exists. I am trying to do this in the same controller just for simplicity sake, but like I said before I am not adding a new one.

Comment: You should explain in general what you're trying to accomplish.  In Angular the controllers have a scope created for them which automatically inherits from the parent scope (which may come from a controller defined higher in the DOM hierarchy).  If you're doing some sort of DOM manipulation or trying to add a behavior you should use a directive, when writing directives you can have one directive that uses the controller from another directive.

Comment: I'm not trying to mess with DOM, just trying to add a simple check of a cookie to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some common functionality that you want to access from multiple controllers (e.g. checking if a cookie exists) then you should put that functionality into a `service` and inject that service into both controllers.

Comment: That is what I was thinking of at the start. Just wanted to make sure there was no other option.